# Is it possible to update the current IPrincipal without creating a new connection in SignalR 2.0.x?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, signalr

We use custom forms authentication in MVC4. We create a FormsAuthenticationTicket with custom data (another authentication ticket for a backend sub system) and store it in a cookie. This cookie is read and dectypted in the  FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate method in global.asax. From the decrypted data we create a custom IPrincipal object that we set as the current User.

We also use a sliding expiration scheme for the ticket and if it's about to expire we create a new ticket and update the cookie and create a new custom IPricipal object.

We have set ut SignalR to ping the server regularly, and the ticket is correctly renenewd.
The problem is that the updated IPrincipal is never propagated to SignalR (it's only set the first time). Is this even possible or do we need to create a new connection when the ticket is renewed?

```
    protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie == null) 
            return;

        var ticketManager = DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(ITicketManager)) as ITicketManager;

        var ticket = ticketManager.DecryptAndValidateTicket(authCookie.Value);

        var newTicket = ticketManager.RefreshTicketIfNeeded(ticket);
        if (newTicket != null) {
            var cookie = ticketManager.CreateCookie(newTicket);
            e.Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            ticket = newTicket;
        }

        var user = ticketManager.Authenticate(ticket);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user;
        HttpContext.Current.User = user;
        e.User = user;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new connection if you want to update the current IPrincipal of a SignalR connection.

The reason is pretty straightforward: SignalR requests can last indefinitely.

Cookies are sent and authentication/authorization occurs at the beginning of a request. This is also when the IPrincipal is set. In SignalR at least, the IPrincipal is stored on the [request itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.irequest%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

I suppose it might be possible to update the IPrincipal if you had references to the active SignalR requests for the given user, but I think your best bet is establishing a new SignalR connection if the IPrincipal changes.

Comment: Thanks! As I expected, but I think it would be great if SignalR updated the IPrincipal on each ping.